# janusgraph python unpack requires a buffer of 4 bytes

Tags: python, python-3.x, janusgraph

I am trying to add vertex graph in Janusgraph.
Connection has been established but when it starts adding the vertex I am getting error:

```
unpack requires a buffer of 4 bytes.
```

My janusgraph is running in remote server and I am connected with VPN.

```
try:
    tx.begin()
```

```
print('Transaction started')
result=g.V().hasLabel('Country').values().limit(1)
print('check result is printing',result)
# Add a vertex
vertex = g.addV('Country').property('name', 'India').next()
print(f'Added vertex with id: {vertex.id}')
```

```
# Commit the transaction
tx().commit()
```

Comment: I'm wondering if there is a mismatch between the version of Gremlin Python you have, and the JanusGraph version. The error you are seeing comes from Python, but could be related to Gremlin ByteCode support or authentication. What versions are you using? Also, are you using Kerberos authentication or anything like that on the server?

Comment: @KelvinLawrence I am using 0.6.2 janusgraph version, we are using basic auth for storage i.e cassandra and elastic search for index. 
I had also tried to run the program over server where janusgraph is hosted but got the same error

Comment: What version of the Gremlin Python client are you using?

Comment: In the TinkerPop github repo, struct.unpack only runs as part of Kerberos authentication. Please provide the full stack trace and details about the authentication configuration.